# What's the difference between the Range1d class (and the other Range classes) and the default range function in Python?

Tags: bokeh

I know, the answer is probably quite simple, but I'm trying to understand what this class does and why it's useful, so that I don't just copy/paste the code from the docs when I need it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no relation between the Python built-in `range` function and Bokeh  `Range` objects. Bokeh `Range` objects are used to specify values on an axis for a plot.

A plot's range may be be numeric and continuous, (vaguely similar to `range`), in which case the `Range` has `start` and `end` properties. Examples are `Range1d` and `DataRange1d`. The latter has the extra behavior of setting `start` and `end` for you by default, so that all your data is shown automatically.

But plot ranges may also be discrete and categorical, e.g a list of month names (which is not similar to `range` at all). An example of that is `FactorRange`.